# Azure MobileService Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently developing an app for windows phone 8.1 with Azure. (I wouldn't really recommend this to you after my experiences). Anyway... I've got Multiple Controller classes in it who really do the same (Check if something in my database already exists and if not it creates it). The problem I have has to be in the Read() function which checks the database if an entry already exists:

```
public async void Read(Device device)
{
    IMobileServiceTable mobileServiceTable = Connect();
    MobileServiceCollection<Device, Device> devices = null;
    try
    {
        devices = await mobileServiceTable.MobileServiceClient.GetTable<Device>().Where(d => d.Manufacturer == device.Manufacturer && d.Model == device.Model).ToCollectionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (_onDeviceControllerListener != null)
        {
            _onDeviceControllerListener.OnError(ControllerError.Error.ReadFromDatabase, e.ToString());
        }
            return;
        }

    if (_onDeviceControllerListener != null && devices != null)
    {
        _onDeviceControllerListener.OnRead(devices);
    }
}
```

This one works perfectly how it should but the oder one which is basically just a copy throws a NullReferenceException by the line "apps = await mobileServiceTab...":

```
public async void Read(Model.App app) 
{
    IMobileServiceTable mobileServiceTable = Connect();
    MobileServiceCollection<Model.App, Model.App> apps = null;
    try {
        apps = await mobileServiceTable.MobileServiceClient.GetTable<Model.App>().Where(a => a.HardwareId == app.HardwareId && a.PackageId == app.PackageId).ToCollectionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (_onAppControllerListener != null)
        {
            _onAppControllerListener.OnError(ControllerError.Error.ReadFromDatabase, e.ToString());
        }
        return;
    }

    if (_onAppControllerListener != null)
    {
        _onAppControllerListener.OnRead(apps);
    }
}
```

Does somebody know what the problem is?
Thanks for helping

Comment: What's the stack trace for your exception?

Comment: Can you step through it and tell us which object is null when the error is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a try...catch block and check for the "MobileServiceInvalidOperationException" exception. Also take a look at the callstack to find out what's happening.

A fiddler trace would also let you know if you made a successful call to the Mobile Service to retrieve the data. Then you can determine if the issue lies in how you handle the data in your code.

Take another look at your MobileServiceContext class and ensure all properties are accounted for especially the properties that use the "Model.App" class. E.g

```
public virtual DbSet<Model.App> SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps.